# Send PHP Email via CRON JOB in CENTOS 6.5

Tags: php, cron, centos, lamp

I am relatively New to CentOS, I have tried a lot in sending an email via CRON JOB using PHP MAIL() but no result. Can I test this in a Local with LAMP environment!!?? I was successful in setting up a CRON JOB but still I am not sure where I was wrong.

Comment: you need to check that sendmail is installed, which is the service used to send emails.

Comment: yes I did install and try but no result. :(

Answer (score 0):

To test your email output locally you may do the following:

Assuming you're in `/Users/<your username>/Sites`:

```
$ mkdir smtp_out && cd cd smtp_out
$ wget https://gist.github.com/Mulkave/5840448/raw/28d1bc680de0ff8f4be2ed8d57784691f3e74342/smtp-catcher.php -O smtp_catcher.php
$ sudo chmod +x smtp_catcher.php
```

In your `php.ini` configuration:

```
sendmail_path = sudo -u <your_username> /Users/<your_username>/Sites/smtp_out/smtp_catcher.php
```

The script `smtp_catcher.php` will attempt to open the email with Apple Mail Client if you're on a mac, it is this line

```
# open up the emlx file (using Apple Mail)
exec('open '.escapeshellarg($filename));
```

feel free to do whatever you want with the file.

You may also need to grant the server permission to open the Mail Client if you're on a mac with:

```
sudo visudo
%www    ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: /Users/<your_username>/Sites/smtp_out/smtp_catcher.php
```

Comment: */1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cronemail.php  -- Is this is correct ??